# What does x,y,z values obtained from accelerometer in Android indicate?

Tags: android

At first I thought:

- x - tilting the phone from left - right and vice versa
- y - upside down and vice versa
- z - lifting the phone up and down

But it doesn't seem like that. Can anyone correct me if I am wrong.

I want to know these values in-order to know the angle of the phone. Is it possible to know it using these values?

Comment: I'm no android developer, but according to the documentation it seems to be as you described. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After obtaining the values from accelerometer into mValuesAccel[3] and gravity values into mValuesMagnet[3],am executing the following methods.

```
enter code here
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, null, mValuesAccel,ValuesMagnet);   
SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, mValuesOrientation);
```

After executing above methods, the values obtained in mValuesOrientation are:

mValuesOrientation[0]: i)if -ve X-axis faces west,then 0 degrees;                         ii)faces south, then -90 degrees;
iii)faces north, then -180 or 180degrees;
iv)faces east, then 90 degrees;
So, it lies between -180 degrees to 180 degrees
NOTE: 1)After converting the X value obtained into degrees, you will get the above values.
2)X-axis wil be from origin to right side,where your origin will be at bottom left of your phone.

mValuesOrientation[1]: if you lift your phone(which is lying on table) such that the top of phone faces sky, then you get -ve values, and +ve values in vice versa
mValuesOrientation[2]: if you move your phone(which is lying on table), like turning a paper in a book, to left side it gives -ve values and right side it gives +ve values.

Answer (score 6):

Acceleration is a vector quantity, i.e. it has importance of its magnitude and also direction in which it is occurring.

Keeping this is mind and see image in link provided by Nicolai Ditlev Krogh Krüger, what we get is the right side of your phone is positive X direction, top side is positive Y direction and the screen side is positive Z direction.

Now Force=mass x acceleration

therefore acceleration = force/mass

Now force of gravity always acts on your device. To keep it from falling you have to apply equal force but in "OPPOSITE" direction.

Now when you put your phone on horizontal table, the table applies an upward force (from back of phone towards the screen), this is positive Z direction. So acceleration here is force/mass of your phone in positive Z direction. Since phone is not moving, means force by table equals gravity and there is no other force in any other directions as well. Force by gravity = mass x 9.8 (approx). Thus you see a value close to +10 for Z parameter of accelerometer and other two are near to zero.

Take one more example. This time hold your phone such that right side of phone is down and left side is up, and you hold your phone from near its ear piece and mic (opposite edges). In this scenario you are applying force against gravity upward, to keep your phone from falling, in negative X direction (remember that in phone positive X direction is pointing towards right side of phone). Thus you will see a value close to -10 for X parameter of accelerometer.

If user holds the phone at an angle (say a) from the horizontal plane (assume user tilt right side of phone down), then force of gravity becomes mass x 9.8 x Cos(a), where 'a' is in degree not radian, along the phone's X axis. Thus acceleration now becomes 9.8 x Cos(a). Since Max value of Cos(a)=1 (at a=0 degree), user will see a value less than 9.8 for X parameter of accelerometer for any other angle. If angle a= 60 degree (approx) then X parameter will show value close to 5, as Cos(60)= 0.5.

This is how the values change in the accelerometer output.

User can use the values of X, Y & Z to calculate actual angle of tilt of device from any plane (say horizontal plane).

Suppose X parameter is showing value 6. Then tilt is aCos(6/9.8) (that is Cos inverse and result will be in radians). To convert radians to degrees multiply by 180/pi. Thus final angle of tilt 'a' = aCos(6/9.8)*(180/pi) in degrees.

This how you come to know the tilt of your phone and use it to simulate force on digital objects on the screen. More tilt means more acceleration and hence more force.

Comment: its a good explanation from you @kaustuv but based on your answer, the accelerometer should only give +10 or -10 for any axis when a user catches his phone(not pulling it up or down) but am not getting such values. What i was getting from sensor is value interms of radians.( so it may be some angle related)

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain what to observe when user holds the phone at an angle.

Comment: what you are saying is a more detail way of how we are getting the x,y,z values. I just want to know one thing.So,let me frame my question in another way.
am using following android code to retrieve x,y,z axis
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, null,mValuesAccel, mValuesMagnet);
SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, mValuesOrientation);
and taking x,y,z values from mvaluesOrientation array[0],[1],[2] respectively. Facing(myself) west keeping phone in a angle, if i take these values, it differs from facing north and keeping the phone in same angle.  why the values differ?

Comment: I think you are using compass and not accelerometer. Compass also has 3 parameters - Yaw, Pitch and Roll. Yaw=0 means north, Yaw=90 means east.

Comment: how ur getting the 'a'(angle) value?? Since for calculating angle itself am using X,Y,Z values and you are saying X,Y,Z is obtained through mass*9.8*cos(a), where a is angle.

Comment: I tried to explain the math behind how the value shown on screen changes as you tilt the phone. However i have edited my answer explaining how to know the angle from the values shown on screen.

Comment: hey dude.. when i asked about X value ur saying,
X=mass*9.8*cos(a),where a is angle.
and then if i ask abt the value of 'a' then you are saying
cos-1(X/(9.8*mass)).
what am not able to understand is here you are giving 2 unknown constants and trying to find out one value with other.Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: When i said X=mass*9.8*cos(a), I was trying to explain, how the value that you see on screen (coming from the accelerometer), changes. But, when i said cos-1(X/(9.8*mass)), I meant this is how you can find your phone's tilt angle from the X value of 'accelerometer'.